# Resultant Force causing acceleration when varying mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum

I have a mass with zero velocity in the x direction that I dropped on a moving train.

Its momentum must be conserved then velocity has decrease so there must have been a deceleration yet the only force I have applied is along the the Y axis normal to the x

Assuming zero friction how have what force has caused the deceleration in the x direction. ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the motion in the x-direction.
Just before the dropping body, mass $n$, hits the train, mass $m$ which is moving in the x-direction at a speed of $v_x$, the dropping bodies' momentum in the x-direction is zero.

If there was no friction when the dropping body hit the train the dropping bodies momentum in the x-direction would still be zero as there is no way that the train can exert a force on the dropping body.

With friction present then because when the dropping body hits the train there is relative movement between the train and the dropping body there is a friction force on the dropping body due to the train and a friction force on the train due to the dropping body.
The frictional force continue to act as long as there is relative movement between the dropping body and the train.

The frictional force increases the speed the dropping body in the x-direction and reduces the speed of the train in the opposite direction x-direction until they are moving at the same speed $w_x$ in the x-direction.

Treating the train and the dropped body as one system which has no external forces on it in the x-direction the conservation of momentum can be used.

$m\;v_x + n\;0 = (m+n)\; w_x$

This is equivalent to saying that the velocity of the centre of mass of the dropped body and train system stays constant.

When one does the sums it is foungd the the kinetic energy of the train before the collision is greater than the combined kinetic energy of the train and dropped object after collision.
The decrease is explain by the frictional forces doing work (heat is generated) when there is relative motion between the train and the dropped object.

Answer (score 0):

If the two bodies were to move along with one another after the impact, then there have to be an interaction between them along the $x$-axis.

Though it is important to note that in absence of any external force along $x$-axis, the system train+mass will not decelerate. The train will undergo a decrease in speed from $v_0$ to $v_1$ while the dropped mass will undergo an **increase** in horizontal speed from $0$ m/s to $v_1$, in such a way that the center of mass of the system keeps going with the same horizontal velocity.

Answer (score 0):

Two bodies collided : the truck and the weight. During the collision there is a contact force between them (possibly friction) which opposes their relative motion. (If there were no friction force the truck would slide underneath the weight.) The truck pushes forward on the weight, accelerating it; the weight pushes backward on the truck, decelerating it. As a result of the collision the momentum of both bodies changed - the momentum of the truck decreased, the momentum of the weight increased.